# WCF Data Service / Oracle - Performance issues

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, wcf-data-services

I'm using the following to surface data from Oracle: 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkWCF/WCFEntityFramework.htm

I have 2 WCF data services one is pointing to a SQL Server database, the other is pointing to an Oracle instance. 
The one that points to SQL is lightening fast, the one to Oracle is horrifically slow, upwards of 15-20 seconds returning results.

I tried running the exact same query on Oracle via SQL plus, it works just fine, returns results great. I switched out the data provider from ODP.NET to the Microsoft's .NET provider for Oracle, still no improvement. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx

Any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with 2 things - 
1. The ODP.NET driver is painfully slow.
2. Malformed (my bad) queries, when using the restful API, or actually, when using WCF Data services, be sure to be very specific with your queries.

Comment: Having the same experience... what was your final solution?  What  was wrong with the query?